# iframe autosize with expandable content

Tags: javascript

I have a page that I'm building that needs to use an iframe so that we can have a wrapper around content and also show it without. I've been able to come up with some JS that auto detects the height of the iframe but the content within expands and the iframe doesn't recognize this. I'm assuming I need to come up with some sort of onclick in the framed content that will trigger the iframe to resize again but so far have been stuck.

Below is the JS that I have in the head section for the function that autosizes the iframe:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">



    function autoResize(id){
        //alert('check');
        var newheight;
        var newwidth;

        if(document.getElementById){
            newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight;
            newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollWidth;
        }
        //alert(newheight);
        //alert(newwidth);
        document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
        document.getElementById(id).width= (newwidth) + "px";

    }


    </script>
```

And then this is the iframe with the onload and ID:

```
<iframe id="showcase" src="index.html" onload="javascript: autoResize('showcase');" frameborder="0" width="800px" height="4000" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Thanks for any help and I hope I was specific enough on this question.

Comment: Do you really cannot use AJAX for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I assume you can use [DOM Mutation Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents) to set an event handler of `offsetWidth`/`offsetHeight` attributes of `body` object inside the frame changes and call `autoResize`.

Again, I am not sure this can work.